# Joomla 1.7 - show same menu, different content to guest and members

Tags: joomla

In Joomla 1.7 I would like to show the same menus to both logged in members and guests. But for members I want to display the member-only content for each menu entry and for guests I want to show sales copy.

I would prefer to use native ACL, but it isnt happening.

I've tried using this:
http://docs.joomla.org/Access_Control_List/1.6-2.5/Tutorial#Allowing_Guest-Only_Access_to_Menu_Items_and_Modules

but i cant get it to work - the supposedly restricted content for Guests is shown to both guests AND logged in members.

ANyone know another solution?
many thanks
Dex

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question and the link above explain how to build a guest specific content (and it works nice) but it doesn't explain how to keep a unique menu entry (always visible = public) which present 2 differents contents, for exemple (which is my need) :

- for guest : login page
- for registered : a specific content

Since the scope (guest / public / etc) is defined at the entry menu level, this is a problem, you must set it to public in order to always show it. So how to say to the main component to be shown or not ?

Solution 1 : Create an entry menu, TEST for exemple, in guest : content = guest content Create another entry menu with the same name TEST (but a different alias), in registered : content = registered content This simulate a unique menu entry but with differents contents.

Solution 2 : Create an entry menu, TEST for exemple, in public, set a blank component to it. In the page TEST add different modules with different scopes (guest & registered). Put component as module by installing a joomla extension which allow that. I didn't tried by this should work too.

But these two solutions still are workarounds for me... Is there a better way to do the job ??

Thanks.

ps : I am working with joomla 2.5.